# XSLT скажите как можно вставить значение сюда

Tags: xslt

Есть такая функция, выводит строку - параметр  значение, но хотелось бы добавить параметр для окрашивания строки, решил сделать передачу 3го параметра класс

```
  <xsl:template name="RowHtmlDecorator">
    <xsl:param name="title"/>
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:param name="class"/>
    <xsl:if test="$value!='' and $value!=' ' and $value!='  '">
      <tr class="СЮДА">
        <td align="right" class="first_column">
          <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
        </td>
        <td class="second_column">
          <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Там где слово СЮДА, нужно вставить значение переменно $class. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два способа

1. Обрамить переменную фигурными скобками

   ```
   <tr class="{$class}">
   ```
2. Использовать `<xsl:attribute>`

   ```
   <td>
     <xsl:attribute name="class">
       <xsl:value-of select="$class"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
     ........
   </td>
   ```

P.S. А этот код

```
<xsl:if test="$value!='' and $value!=' ' and $value!='  '">
```

будет логично переписать так

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space($value) != ''">
```

Comment: Все по красоте! Спасибо!

Comment: Я там еще вопрос по xslt создам как вывести массив значений в определенном порядке. Если будет минутка глянь пожалуйста)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797944/xslt-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5