# XSLT как вывести массив значений в определенном порядке

Tags: xslt

Есть вот такой XML кусок

```
   <Data>
       <parameters>
         <name>имя_параметра</name>
         <value>значение_параметра</value>
       </parameters>
       <parameters>
         <name>имя_параметра</name>
         <value>значение_параметра</value>
       </parameters>
       <!-- ....... -->
   </Data>
```

Возможно как то можно делать селект по значению тега? 
А то я сейчас придумал только делать перебор всех значений и если оно которое мне надо - вывожу и так где то 10 раз

```
<xsl:for-each select="./Data/parameters">
  <xsl:if test="./name='имя_параметра'">
    <!-- вывожу -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Может как то можно более рационально без перебора всех значений?

Comment: я нашел решение, сделал это с помощью селекта по значению тега
Data/parameters[name='имя_параметра']

Comment: В каком порядке Вам нужно вывести имена? По алфавиту?

Comment: Если какая-то своя сортировка, то укажите каким процессором делаете преобразование

Comment: помог именно селект по значению тега, я не знал что так можно, сортировка нужна так сказать заказчика, чтобы тут это потом это и тд, именно в ручную надо вывести

Comment: Если назовете процессор, то возможно, подскажу еще более простой вариант. Через `<xsl:sort>` и написание своей функции-компаратора

Comment: а что значит процессор? я просто для просмотра в браузере делаю